# Cannot get each single line length from file, with given imports only

Tags: java

This program reads the file named "Readme.txt" and displays each line with line numbers and then displays the average line length after reading all the lines.

The issue I have here is that I get 
"Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found""

**NOTE:** I'm only suppose to use the imports in my code, nothing else.

I've tried using sc.nextLine().length() to determine each lines length however, I encounter that error message.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LineReader {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Readme.txt"));
    int count = 0;
    double total = 0;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        count++;
        total += sc.nextLine().length();
        System.out.println(count + " " + sc.nextLine());


    }

    double avg = total / count;
    System.out.println("The average line length is " + avg );

}
```

---

```
Expected: 
1 I love pizza 
2 Bacon is delicious 
3 I am hungry 
The average line length is 13.6

Actual:
1 I love pizza
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at LineReader.main(LineReader.java:15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `Scanner.nextLine()` you consume one line. You currently call it twice in your loop. Save the reference locally. Like,

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    count++;
    total += line.length();
    System.out.println(count + " " + line);
}
```